# Django Form Get Foreign Key Data In Add Form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a "note" to an "applicant," but in the create note form I would like the applicant's name to show above the form. Right now the tags ( {{ applicant.full_name }} ) are not working in the create form template. Here is part of my CreateNote view currently. Thank you for any assistance.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        applicant_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        applicant = Applicant.objects.get(pk=applicant_pk)
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.applicant = applicant
        self.object.save()
        return super(NoteCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Did you pass the `applicant` to the *context*? Looks like it simply does not exists in the context data (`get_context_data`).

Comment: What would be the best implementation of that?